# the jquery.jscrollpane.min.js not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using

> *jquery.jscrollpane.min.js*

and

> *jquery-1.6.1.min.js*

but the scroll is not working... I have uploaded all these file on my website... the website runs ok except the scrolling :

http://radioone.site40.net/

here is script.js where i am using function from jscrollpane:

```
$(window).load(function() {



    // scroll
    $('.playlist-scroll-pane').jScrollPane({
        showArrows: false,
        verticalGutter: 10,
        verticalDragMinHeight: 68,
        verticalDragMaxHeight: 68
    });
```

this is code in the index file(music player):

```
<div class="jp-playlist">
                      <div class="playlist-scroll-pane jspScrollable" style="overflow:scroll; padding: 0px; width: 242px;" tabindex="0">

                      <div class="jspContainer" style="width: 242px; height: 236px;">
                        <div class="jspPane" style="padding: 0px; top: 0px; width: 212px;">
                            <ul style="display: block;">
                                <p><li class="jp-playlist-current">
                                    <div>
```

Answer (score 0):

change height of jspContainer and include jquery.mousewheel.js and mwheelIntent.js files

Comment: jquery.mousewheel.js and mwheelIntent.js is already included and how much do you think the height should be??